# Access slide in slider by url

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I am using the slit slider off the website https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/24/slit-slider-revised/

How can I access a slide by url.

for ex. the 2nd slider has an id="test".
So I should be able to access this slid by http://../#test?

This is not working, can someone help me out with this?

Gr

Comment: Are you trying to implement an entire slider functionality by link, or simply an image as a part of your slider?

Comment: I want each slide accessible by a link for ex. slide 1 http://.../#1, slide 2 http://.../#2 ...

Comment: What do you mean by 'accessible'? Do you want it so that each slide has a link to a specific page when clicked? You need to be very precise in your questions, and not vague. What is it you EXACTLY want. It's hard to read minds. Provide examples if possible.

Comment: yes, I want every slide has a link.